# How to trigger automatic start of job in Jenkins on a custom(non master) branch?

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

How to trigger automatic start of job in Jenkins on a custom(non master) branch?

There doesn't seem to be a setting on a Gitlab side for that: Gitlab -> Project -> Settings -> Jenkins CI Integrations to set up a webhook for some other branch, like "dev" f.e. :(
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled on the Jenkins side.

Go to your job under *Source Code Management* -> *Branches to build*

Be sure to also fill out the Repository URL and credentials.
Jenkins should only run builds on pushes to the given branches.

[SCM section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1HcI.png)

Make sure to also check the ***Build when a change is pushed to GitLab***
box under Build Triggers. You will need to install the GitLab plugin for Jenkins to see this option.

You can choose which branches to build by clicking *advanced* -> *allowed branches*

[GitLab Build Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lwqS.png)

Comment: GitLAB, no GitHUB :(

Comment: added instructions for GitLAB